# Merge data from two tables into single column of another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to merge data from multiple tables into single column of another table.

Example:

**Table A**

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
10
20
```

**Table B**

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3
13
99
```

I want my **o/p** in **Table C in Col1** as

```
Col1
10
20
13
99
```

I did (part of query)

```
Select Col1 from A
Union
Select Col1 from B
```

but it is not giving me this desired result

Comment: Can you explain "not giving me this desired result"?  What result are you getting?

Comment: @Craig im getting 1,2,3,4 4 values under column C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SELECT` appears correct (you may want to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` to avoid elimination of duplicates).

If you want the results to be in the third table `C`, you need to make an `INSERT` from your `SELECT`, like this:

```
INSERT INTO C (Col1)
(
    SELECT Col1 from A
UNION ALL
    SELECT Col1 from B
)
```

Comment: not getting values of table b into table c. Only table A values are coming

Comment: @Vinayak That is strange. You didn't miss the parentheses around the two `SELECT`s and the `UNION ALL` operator, did you?

Comment: i ran this query SELECT Col1 from A UNION ALL SELECT Col1 from B only values from table A is showing in o/p

Comment: @Vinayak It works perfectly on sqlfiddle ([link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19e39/2)).

Comment: my bad i missed some part of the query (not the parentheses) its correct